# Android Soft Keyboard Obscures EditTexts in ScrollView

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a TableLayout that fills_parent inside of a ScrollView.  Everything works perfectly except when the Soft Keyboard is shown it obscures the last few EditTexts.  Technically, the screen can't be scrolled down any more since without the Keyboard showing, the screen fits all the content.  It's just that when the Keyboard is showing, I can not scroll lower to see the remaining EditTexts without hiding the keyboard and allowing the user to just select and enter values into one of the lower EditTexts.  Using [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/on-screen-inputs.html), I've tried:

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode((int)SoftInput.AdjustPan);
```

and

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode((int)SoftInput.AdjustResize);
```

and

```
[Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustPan)]
```

and

```
[Activity(WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize)]
```

and

```
Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.AltFocusableIm, WindowManagerFlags.AltFocusableIm);
```

That one just prevented the keyboard from coming up at all.  Which isn't what I need. I need my content to adjust to be shown above the Keyboard when visible so that I can continue scrolling to the very bottom EditText with Keyboard shown.  An excerpt from the very long xml.  The table is dynamically populated in code.

```
<ScrollView
 android:id="@+id/peScroll"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_below="@id/security">
   <TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/poweredEquip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dip">        
    <TableRow
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_unselected"
      android:gravity="center">
      <TextView
        android:text="Serial"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_column="1"/>
     </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution but decided to just add a large marginBottom to the last row.