# ScrollView doesn't scrolls if soft keyboard is visible

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

I'm using a simple layout for a login screen which contains a bar at the top and the necessary items for user to login or go to the sign up activity.

All the elements fit nicely on the screen until the virtual keyboard appears. The Android soft keyboard obscures part of the form, and I want to use a ScrollView so the user can scroll and be able to see all the elements.

But, even with ScrollView, I can't scroll to see the bottom of the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFCB05"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:gravity="top" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_below="@+id/include1"
 >



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="@string/usuario"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtUsuario"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/usuario" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dip" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/senha"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtSenha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/senha"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logarBtn"
        android:layout_width="93dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:text="@string/logar" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logarBtn"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dip"
        android:linksClickable="true"
        android:text="@string/cadastrar"
        android:textColor="#0000CC"
        android:textSize="18dp" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I think I could do this: [Android Soft Keyboard Obscures EditTexts in ScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10388326/android-soft-keyboard-obscures-edittexts-in-scrollview) but it doesn't seem like the best practice.

Does anyone know of a better way to make it scroll properly?

Comment: Shouldn't clicking outside the EditText remove the soft keyboard from the screen anyway? Isn't it designed to do that when the input field loses focus?

Comment: My EditText only loses focus if I touch in another EditText or Button, so the soft keyboard keeps appearing.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class CustomScrollView extends ScrollView {

  private int scrollOffset = 0;

  public CustomScrollView (final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public void setScrollOffset (final int scrollOffset) {
    this.scrollOffset = scrollOffset;
  }

  @Override
  protected int computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen (final Rect rect) {
    // adjust by scroll offset
    int scrollDelta = super.computeScrollDeltaToGetChildRectOnScreen(rect);
    int newScrollDelta = (int) Math.signum(scrollDelta) * (scrollDelta + this.scrollOffset);
    return newScrollDelta;
  }
}
```

Use this Custom Scroll View instead of the normal Scroll View. Change the value of scrollOffset to achieve the desired result (scrollOffset = 10 means extra 10dp will be scrolled down when soft keyboard opens) Make sure  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` is added in the activity

Answer (score 2):

Check out the following link:

[Android: ScrollView not scrolling with keyboard out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343355/android-scrollview-not-scrolling-with-keyboard-out)

This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ideal way of doing it is below.

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

But, when views are already fitting inside a screen, even if softkeypad opens up scrolling will be disabled.