# Android: ScrollView not scrolling with keyboard out

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

I've got a layout with some views, from which one is an EditText. The layout easily fits on one page, BUT, when the soft keyboard is out, the layout doesn't scroll.
Here's a recap of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <CheckBox/>

            <TextView/>

            <LinearLayout>
                <EditText>
                    <requestFocus />
                </EditText>
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView/>

            <LinearLayout>
                <Spinner/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And in my manifest I have declared the attribute:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```

Does anyone know why it doesn't work and how to make sure it does work?

Comment: for Android 5, check out this related post: [Android - adjust scrollview when keyboard is up for android 5.0 (lollipop)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167176/android-adjust-scrollview-when-keyboard-is-up-for-android-5-0-lollipop)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Okay, apparently the ScrollView's `android:layout_height` mustn't be set to `wrap_content`. I set it to `match_parent` and set the `android:layout_above` to the button on the bottom of the page.

Don't ask me why, but this fixed the issue.

Comment: `layout_above` whatever view you want to have fixed at the bottem of the screen

Comment: what if no fixed view at bottom?

Comment: Doesn't work if the ScrollView only takes up a part of the screen. If you have a layout at the bottom of your activity that acts like a footer, this solution will not work.

Answer (score 68):

I had the same problem and I checked my activity in the manifest, and the reason why it wasn't working is because I didn't use this property:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Now it works great and no need to do additional anchors.

Comment: this property blocked the scrolling while I was editing text inside an editText. I removed this property and now scrolling works. Not sure why, but none of the solutions in this thread worked for me, only deleting this line.

Answer (score 29):

In my case, nothing of the above worked.

I had `item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` in my theme. And it was fixed by setting `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the parent layout where is my scrollview.

Answer (score 13):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` to your  tag in AndroidManifest.xml file. This will cause the screen to be resized to the left over space after the soft keyboard is shown. So, you will be able to scroll easily.

Answer (score 6):

If your First Fragment Scroll perfectly and the second fragment did not scroll then you should use the second fragment replace and do below things

1.Add in ScrollView

```
android:fillViewport="true"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

2.Add in Manifest

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible"
```

If you add fragment then my suggestion is you need to Replace the Fragment

Answer (score 5):

In my case any of the solution above does not work until I **REMOVE**

`getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);`

in my activity, I use that code to get a full screen display. Maybe for certain cases, try to remove any setup of full screen to make any of the above solution works.

Comment: Thanks your solution helped me , I had similar problem but I added fullscreen in styles.xml

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to **Remove** the following property from my style to make it work .

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```

Comment: Works as expected, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My problem was with a HorizontalScrollView. In my case I had to set HorizontalScrollView to:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

And remove:

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/closeButton"
 android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml the activity is set to:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode=""
```

I hope this helps anyone comming across this weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, what solved this was setting a missing constraint in the Bottom. My ScrollView had top, right, and left constraints, but no bottom one. After restricting it from all sides, it started to overlap the above textview, which prompted me to try putting the height to 0dp, and that seemed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem.

Before changing

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

After changing

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Now it works fine and no need to do additional anchors.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Try to set ScrollView as your parent layout. It works like charm for me!

Answer (score -7):

```
<activity 
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
>
```

**try this In android manifest** ..

Comment: That answer was already given by [Ciprian in 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18184481/3004518)