# Android - adjust scrollview when keyboard is up for android 5.0 (lollipop)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview

I have a problem on android lollipop, screen doesn't adjust size when the softkeyboard comes up.

This is my manifest intro example from one of the activity i made:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize"
```

Is there something new that is added and we have to take into account for android 5.0 ? The scrollview works fine on android < 5.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the problem was that it didn't work with translucent status bar and i had to set

```
 android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

in my main layout

Comment: You saved me! Thanks you. I was looking for this answer for 2 days.

Answer (score 5):

For the guy's who still have this issue even with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the ScrollView.

I found few ways to solve it:

1. use as root `fragment.xml` layout RelativeLayour and put `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` inside. ScrollView use as a child of RelativeLayour.

```
<RelativeLayout android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <ScrollView/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

2. use NestedScrollView instead of ScrollView.

Both options should be used with `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and works on Android 5 with `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>` flag.
`

Comment: Im not sure how to implement. Could you be please more verbose? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing I've tried has worked and Ive gone through every single concievable combination of different Manifest settings etc to no avail.

Its a little hacky but it works beautifully for me:

```
((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootLayout)).addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                scrollToLatest(); // Do your scrolling!
            }
        });
```