# ScrollView doesn't work when keyboard is up

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to use a `<scrollview>` layout that consists of some `EditTexts` and a linear of `Buttons` at the bottom, but the problem is when the soft keyboard is out, the layout doesn't `scroll` and it hides the `Buttons`' linear completely and the main linear `(@+id/main)` goes out of the screen!

Here's a recap of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#03A9F4"
  android:gravity="center"
  >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="310dip"
    android:layout_height="485dip"
    android:background="#03A9F4"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="435dip"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
      android:background="@drawable/border_signup_signin_auth">

      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="70dip"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:ignore="UselessLeaf">
        </LinearLayout>


        <ScrollView
          android:id="@+id/ScrollMain"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:isScrollContainer="false"
          >

          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="80dip"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip">

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="80dip"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip">

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  />
              </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="70dip"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip">

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  />
              </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="70dip"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingEnd="10dip"
              tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

              <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="60dip"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="5dip"
              android:paddingRight="5dip">

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="test"
                  android:textSize="16sp"/>
              </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btnGuest"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="test"
                  android:textSize="16sp"
                  />
              </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

      </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerInParent="false"
      android:contentDescription="TODO"
      app:srcCompat="@mipmap/signup"
      tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And in the manifest I have tried the attribute:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Also, I have tried same questions' solutions like:

- [Page scroll when soft keyboard popped up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989130/page-scroll-when-soft-keyboard-popped-up)
- [Android:ScrollView not scrolling with keyboard out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15343355/android-scrollview-not-scrolling-with-keyboard-out)

But didn't work for me.

Does anyone know why it doesn't work?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution.
I just changed the `Scrollview's` parent to `RelativeLayout` (instead of `LinearLayout`). 
I don't know why, but it fixed the issue. Maybe in layouts that its main Layout is RelativeLayout, Scrollview's parent should be a RelativeLayout! **(But I'm not sure)**

> Here is fixed code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#03A9F4"
  android:gravity="center"
  >

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="310dip"
    android:layout_height="485dip"
    android:background="#03A9F4"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="435dip"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
      android:background="@drawable/border_signup_signin_auth">

      <!--It changed to RelativeLayout and fix the problem-->
      <RelativeLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="70dip"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          tools:ignore="UselessLeaf">
        </LinearLayout>


        <ScrollView
          android:id="@+id/ScrollMain"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:isScrollContainer="false"
          >

          <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="80dip"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip">

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="80dip"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip">

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  />
              </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="70dip"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="10dip"
              android:paddingRight="10dip">

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
              </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  />
              </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="70dip"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingEnd="10dip"
              tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

              <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="60dip"
              android:baselineAligned="false"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:paddingLeft="5dip"
              android:paddingRight="5dip">

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="test"
                  android:textSize="16sp"/>
              </LinearLayout>

              <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                  android:id="@+id/btnGuest"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:text="test"
                  android:textSize="16sp"
                  />
              </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

      </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerInParent="false"
      android:contentDescription="TODO"
      app:srcCompat="@mipmap/signup"
      tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And it wasn't necessary to add anything to Java's file or Manifest.
[image: output]

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/profile_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|adjustPan"
    tools:context="com.example.user22.hotelxp.Activity.MyProfileActivity">


   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/imageView"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerInParent="false"
       android:contentDescription="TODO"
       app:srcCompat="@mipmap/signup"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
       tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/profile_layout_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/layout_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="70dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:paddingRight="10dip">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:paddingRight="10dip">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dip"
                    android:baselineAligned="false"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
                    android:paddingRight="10dip">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingEnd="5dip"
                        tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="70dip"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingEnd="10dip"
                    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry">

                    <com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>


        </ScrollView>


    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="5dip">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textSize="16sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnGuest"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="test"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In AndroidManifest :

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
```

Comment: Thanks.It really helps. I'll post the solution after making sure that is correct.

Comment: @Eмαd You can accept my answer if it solves your problem. If you face any problem in this then let me know i will edit this.

Comment: Thank you Vishva, I posted the solution.

Comment: @Eмαd As my answer is helpful to you then you can accept my answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` to android manifest where your Activity is called

or

add this line on `onCreate()` method

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```